# Preserving raster .tif.aux.xml with gdalwarp

Tags: raster, attribute-table, gdalwarp

I created a raster in R and wrote it to a .tif file which created an associated `.tif.aux.xml` file with the raster attribute table. Later I wanted to call `gdalwarp` to downsample and/or crop it. However, it does not create a new `.tif.aux.xml` with the attribute table, so the raster's attributes are lost. How can I preserve the attributes?

### reproducible example

#### R code to generate raster files

```
library(raster)

m <- matrix(sample(1:5, size=100, replace=TRUE), ncol = 10)
r <- raster(m)
r <- ratify(r)
levels(r) <- c('city','mountain','river','lake','ocean')
colortable(r) <- c('blue','green','red','purple','yellow')

r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
values(r) = 1
r[51:100] = 2
r[3:6, 1:5] = 3
r <- ratify(r)

rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$landcover <- c("Pine", "Oak", "Meadow")
rat$code <- c(12,25,30)
levels(r) <- rat
r

colortable(r) <- c('black', 'darkgreen','darkred','goldenrod')
plot(r)

# Write the raster
r_tif <- writeRaster(r, 'testraster.tif')
```

This creates two files, `testraster.tif` and `testraster.tif.aux.xml`

Now I execute this system command:

```
gdalwarp -tr 1 1 testraster.tif testrasterwarped.tif
```

At this point if I go back to R and call:

```
raster('testrasterwarped.tif')
```

I get no attribute table:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 171, 342, 58482  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 162, -81, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : C:/Users/qread/Documents/temp/testrasterwarped.tif 
names      : testrasterwarped 
values     : 0, 255  (min, max)
```

But if I manually copy `testraster.tif.aux.xml` to `testrasterwarped.tif.aux.xml` I get:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 171, 342, 58482  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 162, -81, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : C:/Users/qread/Documents/temp/testrasterwarped.tif 
names      : testrasterwarped 
values     : 0, 255  (min, max)
attributes :
 ID category
  0         
  1     Pine
  2      Oak
  3   Meadow
```

How to preserve the attribute table to begin with?